# Python: Apply Change to Each Item in List

Tags: python

Sorry I'm new to python. I was wondering if there was a faster way to do one small change to each element in a list.

Say I have the following list:

```py
names = ['bob', 'sally', 'robert']
```

Now say I want to capitalize each element in the list. The only way I can think of to do that is like this:

```py
new_names = []
for name in names:
    first_letter = name[0]
    # if the letter is lowercase, subtract its ascii value by 32 to get the uppercase equivalent
    if ord(first_letter) <= 122 and ord(first_letter) >= 97:
        first_letter = chr(ord(first_letter)-32)
    new_name = first_letter + name[1:]
    new_names.append(new_name)
```

This gives the desired result, but I was wondering if there was a faster, easier way to do the same thing.

**I want to be able to apply any function to each element in a list.**

Thanks!

Edit:

I ended up going with the following:

```py
names = ['bill', 'James']
new_names = [(chr(ord(x[0])-32)*(97<=ord(x[0])<=122)or x[0])+x[1:]for x in names]
```

Thank you to Toranian for suggesting list comprehensions!

Comment: Research [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  It helps to know what they are called 

Comment: Try this - `[name.capitalize() for name in names]` maybe?  As @MarkTolonen suggested List Comp. is faster way.

Comment: There are two ways: create a new list element by element, or use `for i in range(len(names)):`.

Comment: I wanted to know how to apply a function to every element in a list. The capitalization was just an example of something i might want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the most "Pythonic" way to do this would be to use a list comprehension. Python also has a built in method called `capitalize()`, which is exactly what you're looking for.

To put the two together, we can do this:

```
names = [name.capitalize() for name in names]
```

What we are doing here is iterating over each name in the names list, and then just changing the first letter to a capital.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is different than earlier post?

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed, informative answer. It will be a great help to me in my projects.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built-in `str.capitalize()` method that does this. You can use it in a list comprehension.

```
new_names = [name.capitalize() for name in names]
```

There's also a similar method `str.title()`, which capitalizes each word in the string, not just the first letter of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate, which gives the index and the item:

```
names = ['bob', 'sally', 'robert']

for i, name in enumerate(names):
    names[i] = name[0].upper() + name[1:]

print(names)
```

which gives:

```
['Bob', 'Sally', 'Robert']
```

Here, I've used `upper()`. But Barmar's answer of `capitalize`/`title` is even better.